# How can I populate a select element from JQuery UI Autocomplete search results?

Tags: jquery-ui, select, autocomplete, populate

I am fairly new to JQuery and Javascript...

Currently I am using the following technique or code to populate input boxes from a JQuery UI autocomplete set of search results...

```
    var PopulateFields = function(event, ui){
                $('#Custid').val(ui.item.Custid);
                $('#Alpha1').val(ui.item.Alpha1);
                $('#Alpha2').val(ui.item.Alpha2);
                $('#CustName').val(ui.item.CustName);
                $('#Address1').val(ui.item.Address1);
                $('#Address2').val(ui.item.Address2);
                $('#City').val(ui.item.City);
                $('#State').val(ui.item.State);
    }
    $( "#search-by-custname" ).autocomplete({
                source: "cust_search_by_name.php",
                minLength: 4,
                select: PopulateFields
    });
```

The php script is grabbing the info from a database and squirting it back via JSON in the following format:

```
    [{"label":"A Tire Store","value":"A Tire Store","Custid":"10000","Alpha1":"COD123456","Alpha2":"TIRE","CustName":"A Tire Store","Address1":"123 Cherry Lane","Address2":"","City":"City of Bla","State":"FL","Zip":"555555"}]
```

This works wonderfully with input boxes.
However, if I wanted to make State a select box, how would I populate that Select box with the existing value in the customer record?

Or, is that impossible?

I am trying to create a data entry form, and one of the features I want to have is when they search for a customer record to edit, that their search will populate all fields on the form and then they can edit them.

I thought a select box for State would save me some data validation logic...

My other thought was to use a read only input box for the State (because I know JQuery UI autocomplete will populate that), and then create a "State Selector" Select box that would populate the read only input "State" box for re-submission.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you've tried this and it's failed?  Because if you have a select similar to

```
<select id="State">
    <option>AK</option>
    <option>FL</option>
    <option>WY</option>
</select>
```

then calling `$("#State").val("FL")` will work.

Comment: Ok... Forgive my ignorance, but, how will hard coding the value of "FL" pull that data from the JSON string coming back from the database?  Currently I have tried $('#State').val(ui.item.State); to try and populate the select box, but, that, does not work.  That piece of code will however, populate an input box.

Comment: OK... I figured out part of the problem.  I had forgotten that I used the JQuery UI Combobox (Autocomplete) to make the select box pretty.  So the "Acutal" Select Box was getting populated, but, it was not showing in the JQuery UI Combobox (Autocomplete).  I still have no idea how to make it populate the JQuery UI Combobox (Autocomplete).  I foolishly forgot to mention that I was using that feature of the JQuery UI from their examples. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The "hard coded" FL value was just an example.  I was trying to gather more information about what you were experiencing.  So, are you using the Combobox from the jQuery UI Autocomplete Demo?